# Using Matplotlib & Abaqus 6.12

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently making a plug-in for abaqus using python. I've searched high and low for a solution to this problem. Ive managed to install matplotlib 1.3.1 into abaqus and its relevent modules (Six, numpy, dateutil, pytz and pyparsing) by simply copying them into the abaqus site-packages folder. It seems Abaqus 6.12 has numpy 1.4 inbuilt but this needs to be updated to 1.5 or later...I simply deleted and replaced it with 1.8.0. I encountered the 'Tkinter' error and resolve it using the following:

```
    import sys        
    sys.path.append("C:\Python26\Lib\lib-tk")
    import Tkinter
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Now I can seem to use matplotlib. However whenever I use the plt.plot() function in my plug-in, abaqus freezes. When I shut abaqus down the plot opens soon after. Im not really sure what is going on here, has anyone else experienced this problem or have a potential solution??

I hope this is clear, please ask if I need to elaborate on anything else.

Comment: I am using Abaqus 6.11 with NumPy 1.6.1 and Matplotlib 1.1.0, and it works without freezing the application... maybe you can try changing the Matplotlib version... be sure they are compatible with the Abaqus installation (32 or 64 bit)...

Comment: After some experimenting with earlier versions I managed to get the .plot() feature to work I didnt realise it would make a difference. The plt.show() function dodesnt work but this is a step forward! Cheers Saullo Castro!